# Lightweight utility/program to run a command after a random delay

Tags: linux, command-line, random

I need to randomize the time before a given command starts. I realize it's relatively trivial to do this within a script, or to write a "wrapper" script to do this, but I'm wondering if anyone knows a lightweight binary program that's already out there that will accomplish this without requiring an interpreter to be loaded.

EDIT: More specifically, I do not want to involve bash in any way.  Assume for the sake of argument that no shell is available and I'm invoking this from a non-interactive program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want finer-grained control than [maxschlepzig's nice bash incantations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14632/lightweight-utility-program-to-run-a-command-after-a-random-delay/14636#14636), it's a reasonably easy thing to just code up:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){
  useconds_t mdelay=0, delay;
  if (argc<3){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s <delay (in milli-seconds)> <command> <args>* :\n\trun commands with a random delay\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  mdelay=atol(argv[1]);
  /* seed random number generator with the time */
  srand(((unsigned int)time(NULL))%RAND_MAX); 
  delay = mdelay * (rand() / (1.0 + RAND_MAX));
  usleep(delay*1000);
  execvP(argv[2],getenv("PATH"),argv+2);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile with something like `gcc randomdelay.c -o randomdelay` and invoke it like

```
$ randomdelay 10000 echo Hi!
```

If you are doing this is a programming context you might be better off just grabbing the part of the code that picks the random delay for you and calls an `exec` family function (which one you want depends on exactly how you have it specified internally).

Issue here:

- This assumes your systems `rand`/`srand` are sane (not good PRNGs mind you just that they do what the man page says they do). I've been having some trouble with it on my Mac OS X box, where those functions are deprecated in favor of `random`/`srandom`.
- Historically, many implementation of `rand` have had poor numeric characteristics. That shouldn't be a problem in this application, but if it is, replace it with a better PRNG.
- The command line argument handling in this toy is a bit primitive.
- The delay is chosen uniformly from some range. For some applications you might prefer an unbounded distribution like an exponential. Stack Overflow has many questions on how to get non-uniform distributions from a uniform PRNGs.

Comment: This is precisely what I was talking about!  Thanks!!

Comment: you could use *rand48() family instead of rand().

Answer (score 6):

In `bash` you can do it like this:

```
sleep $(($RANDOM%3)) && some_command
```

thus waiting between 0 and 2 seconds before executing the command. Or choose another interval.

Or if `$RANDOM` is not available you can try `jot`:

```
sleep `jot -r 1 0 3` && some_command
```

Sure, the random waiting plus executing is not provided by a single binary, but close. Well, having a single binary would be less orthogonal, it would kind of be against the one-tool-for-one-job-principle (and the keep-it-simple-principle (KISS)).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is the `sleep` command. To run your program ten seconds from nowdo something like this:

```
sleep 10 && your_command
```

Next up if you need a little more sophistication would be the [`at`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) scheduler. You could schedule a task to run in an hour like so:

```
echo "your_command" | at +1 hour
```

Comment: This doesn't randomize the time though (I imagine you could pull it off easily enough with `$RANDOM`). It also sounds like the "script" method he wants to avoid -- he wants a binary that does it for some reason

Comment: I was blind to the word "random" when I red the question. Sleep would would still work if you feed it a random number.